# Dealing with multiple DTO's while making web client post request in spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webclient

We have a body structure very similar to this :-

{'a' : 'valueA1', 'b' : {'b1' : 'valueB1', 'b2' : 'valueB2'}}

Now, we have a DTO for b which has b1 and b2.

'''

```
public class B {
    private String b1;
    private String b2;
}
```

'''
And similarly we have a DTO for the whole structure, which has values String a and bDTO.

'''

```
public class Z {
private String a;
private B b;
}
```

'''
We make their objects --

B b = new B("valueB1", "valueB2");
Z z = new Z("valueA1", b);

Now I want to make a webClient call using these DTOS.
The way I am trying is :-

'''

```
client1.post()
                    .uri("")
                    .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                    .body(Mono.just(z), Z.class)
                    .retrieve().onStatus(HttpStatus::isError, response -> response.bodyToMono(String.class).map(Exception::new))
                    .bodyToMono(Map.class).block();
```

'''

When I send this request. The request received by the server is :-
{'a' : 'valueA', 'b' : null}

Please, Tell me a way to solve the problem

Comment: Please add the code that constructs `obj_of_a` and the source code of the class `aDTO` from the client and server to your question. If there is a mismatch between the server and client version some attributes might not be parsed and thus set to null.

Answer (score 0):

By default WebClient uses Jackson for JSON serialization. You need to decorate properties with `@JsonProperty` annotation

```
public class B {
        @JsonProperty("b1")
        private String b1;

        @JsonProperty("b2")
        private String b2;

        public B(String b1, String b2) {
            this.b1 = b1;
            this.b2 = b2;
        }
    }

    public class Z {
        @JsonProperty("a")
        private String a;

        @JsonProperty("b")
        private B b;

        public Z(String a, B b) {
            this.a = a;
            this.b = b;
        }
    }
```

Here is a simple test for it

```
B b = new B("valueB1", "valueB2");
Z z = new Z("valueA1", b);

ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(z);

assertEquals("{\"a\":\"valueA1\",\"b\":{\"b1\":\"valueB1\",\"b2\":\"valueB2\"}}", json);
```