# How to pass a body having multiple json values for web client in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webclient

Considering we have a body structure as :-

{'a' : 'valueA1', 'b' : {'b1' : 'valueB1', 'b2' : 'valueB2'}}

What is the ideal way of sending the request to a server having this body in spring boot java.
I have tried webClient and asked a similar question on that.
[Dealing with multiple DTO's while making web client post request in spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72647357/dealing-with-multiple-dtos-while-making-web-client-post-request-in-spring-boot)

Please, let me know if there is a way.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Not sure what you mean by multiple JSON values. From the first look, just create POJO/DTO with 2 properties `a` & `b` where type for `b` is another POJO/DTO

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dealing with multiple DTO's while making web client post request in spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72647357/dealing-with-multiple-dtos-while-making-web-client-post-request-in-spring-boot)

Answer (score 1):

If the issue is that you have an unclear structure of request body, you can use JSONObject

```
    JSONObject b = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject a = new JSONObject();
    a.put("a","value1");
    a.put("b",b);
    b.put("b1",new JSONObject());
```